# Date value is not updated using Angular 2-way binding

Tags: html, angular, .net-core

I have an angular - dotnetcore 2.0 form that makes users update their demographic information. One of the value is birth date. I use the following code to display their birthdate:

```
<input id="dateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="member.dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" #dateOfBirth="ngModel">
```

This doesn't display birthdate. But when I pick a different date then click on submit, it gets updated.

I found out that I can use the following code to display birthday.

```
<input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control"  [ngModel]="member.dateOfBirth | date:'y-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="dateOfBirth = $event" name="dateOfBirth">
```

But this time, the birthdate is displayed but it is not updated.

I also installed npm mpdule `angular-date-value-accessor` and follow its instructions to display birthdate, but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type is member.dateOfBirth? I had some problems with dates in Angular and the solution was to make sure to work with Date objects. If this value is a string which represents an date, try Date.parseDate() in your controller to create a Date object from a string.

Correction:
the method is not parseDate() and you need to instanciate a new Date object:

```
let birthday = new Date( Date.parse( member.dateOfBirth ) );
```

Comment: my date is string. If I work with Date objects, what would be the default value of date object ?

Comment: That means that the value you are assigning to the input is not a valid date format that it accepts. That's why piping with y-MM-d works but updating does not.

Comment: How do we make this conversion? I've been working on this so far no luck.

Comment: I'd recommend using MomentJS. You can return a valid date with a method. Moment allows you to specify the format that you would like.